# shell_exec returns NULL but works in shell

Tags: php, wordpress, shell

In my php script I'm calling another php scipt via `shell_exec()`.

(*The second script only works when executed in the shell, I don't know why but that should not matter here.*)

This is the main script calling the other:

```php
  $result = shell_exec( 'php /html/wp-content/plugins/neuhof/includes/sync/load_products.php' );
  $data = json_decode($result, true);

    foreach($data as $product) {
        if($product['ID'] !== NULL) {
            $wc_product = wc_get_product( $product['ID'] );
            ?>
                <tr id="<?php echo $product['Xhartid']; ?>">
                    <td class="title column-title has-row-actions column-primary page-title"><strong><?php echo $wc_product->get_name(); ?></strong>
                        <div class="row-actions">ID: <?php echo $product['ID']; ?> | <span class="view"> <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $product['ID'] ); ?>" target="_blank"> Anschauen </a> </span></div>
                    </td>
                    <td><?php echo $product['operation']; ?></td>
                    <td class="state">Warten auf WP-Cron...</td>
                </tr>
            <?php
        } else {
            ?>
                <tr id="<?php echo $product['Xhartid']; ?>">
                    <td class="title column-title has-row-actions column-primary page-title"><strong><?php echo $product['Xhartbez']; ?></strong>
                        <div class="row-actions">Noch keine ID vergeben</div>
                    </td>
                    <td><?php echo $product['operation']; ?></td>
                    <td class="state">Warten auf WP-Cron...</td>
                </tr>
            <?php

        }
    }
```

This is the script that should be executed in the shell:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
require_once( 'databases.php' );        // Notwendige Datenbankverbindungen
define('SHORTINIT', true);              // load minimal WordPress
require_once '/html/wp-load.php';       // WordPress loader

// Mit dieser Funktion werden die Datenbank IDs aus dem ERP nutzbar gemacht
function decodeID($id) {
    $unpacked = unpack('Va/v2b/n2c/Nd', $id);
    return sprintf('%08X-%04X-%04X-%04X-%04X%08X', $unpacked['a'], $unpacked['b1'], $unpacked['b2'], $unpacked['c1'], $unpacked['c2'], $unpacked['d']);
}

$sql = "
    SELECT
    Xhartid,
    Xbearbdat,
    Xhartbez
    FROM cms.dbo.xHauptartikel
    WHERE Xinternet = '1'
    ORDER BY Xhartid ASC
";

$erp_ids = $GLOBALS['erp']->query($sql)->fetchALL();

// Code für Abfrage mit WordPress ID
$sql = "
    SELECT distinct
    A.post_id as 'ID',
    A.meta_value as 'Xhartid',
    B.meta_value as 'Xbearbdat'
    FROM
    wp_postmeta A,
    wp_postmeta B
    WHERE
    A.meta_key = 'Xhartid'
    AND
    B.meta_key = 'Xbearbdat'
    AND
    A.post_id = B.post_id
    order by Xbearbdat
    asc
";
$b = $GLOBALS['cms']->query($sql)->fetchALL();

foreach( $erp_ids as $keya => $a ) {
    foreach( $b as $key => $row ) {
        if(decodeID($a['Xhartid']) == $row['Xhartid'] ) {
            if($a['Xbearbdat'] == $row['Xbearbdat']) {
                // Ist akutell
            } else {
                // Aktualisieren
                $list[decodeID($a['Xhartid'])]['operation'] = 'Aktualisieren';
                $list[decodeID($a['Xhartid'])]['ID'] = $row['ID'];
                $list[decodeID($a['Xhartid'])]['Xhartid'] = $row['Xhartid'];
            }
            unset($b[$key]);
            unset($erp_ids[$keya]);
        }
    }
}

// Erstellen
foreach($erp_ids as $row) {
    $list[decodeID($row['Xhartid'])]['operation'] = 'Erstellen';
    $list[decodeID($row['Xhartid'])]['ID'] = NULL;
    $list[decodeID($row['Xhartid'])]['Xhartid'] = decodeID($row['Xhartid']);
    $list[decodeID($row['Xhartid'])]['Xhartbez'] = $row['Xhartbez'];
}

// Löschen
foreach($b as $row) {
    $list[$row['Xhartid']]['operation'] = 'Löschen';
    $list[$row['Xhartid']]['ID'] = $row['ID'];
    $list[$row['Xhartid']]['Xhartid'] = $row['Xhartid'];
}

if($argv[1] == 'count') {
    $ids = 0;
    foreach( $list as $product ) {
        $ids++;
    }
    echo $ids;
} elseif ($argv[1] == 'list') {
    $ids = NULL;
    foreach( $list as $product ) {
        $ids[] = $product['Xhartid'];
    }
    echo json_encode($ids, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
} else {
    echo json_encode($list, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
```

The script returns `NULL` and even if I try `exec()` and get the errors, they are also `NULL`.

I have no idea why this is not working, since `shell_exec('ls')` and simple "hello world" scripts are working fine!

Comment: May I ask why you want to execute the PHP file by shell and not just include the file and  execute the required function?

Comment: It only works when run in the shell, because I need to connect to a MSSQL server and that connection ONLY works from the shell. I don't know why and the hoster could not tell me either... :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (The second script only works when executed in the shell, I don't know why but that should not matter here.)

This is probably because MSSQL connection from second script that you have mentioned is blocked in your webserver environment/php configuration used by webserver.

When you are running second script from shell it may work fine as it is working on different environment. But when you are running second script using shell_exec in php script runned by your webserver it is started with the same webserver environment where it was blocked.

So if you are trying to use shell_exec as a "hack" to omit limitations in your webserver environment then it will not work.

You should contact your server administrator to resolve this.